# Why WCF Discovery Udp channel gets aborted

Tags: wcf, discovery

I want the server to constantly track for available clients using WCF Discovery.

```
        public void Start()
        {
            findCriteria = new FindCriteria(typeof(ITestRunnerAgent))
                               {
                                   Scopes = {new Uri(scope)},
                                   Duration = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(DiscoveryIntervalInMiliseconds)
                               };
            discoveryClient = GetInitilizedDisoveryClient();
            discoveryClient.FindAsync(findCriteria);
        }

        private DiscoveryClient GetInitilizedDisoveryClient()
        {
            var client = new DiscoveryClient(new UdpDiscoveryEndpoint());
            client.FindProgressChanged += OnFindProgressChanged;
            client.FindCompleted += OnFindCompleted;
            return  client;
        }

        private void OnFindCompleted(object sender, FindCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!e.Cancelled)
            {
                // HERE! Sometimes e.Error is not null, but as described in question
                discoveryClient.FindAsync(findCriteria);
            }
        }
```

Unfortunately, sometimes at the point specified by comment i get an aborted Udp channel:

> The communication object,
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.UdpChannelFactory+ClientUdpDuplexChannel,
>   cannot be used for communication
>   because it has been Aborted.

Has anyone ideas why?

Comment: It's rather interesting, that this happens at work only, when connected to a domain network. Everything works fine, when connected to home network.

Comment: In spite of the fact, that AnnouncementClient uses same UDP protocol packets, it works ok. I will try, to make a solution based on Anouncements instead.

Comment: It seems, that yes, it is some infrastructure problem, but not sure, what it can be. I've ended up with using not 'Discovery', but 'Announcements', which are in general similar, except of that first is two way (duplex), the other on is one way

Answer (score 0):

It could be that some network infrastructure at your office is droping the connections.

You should write your code to check for aborted communication, and recover from it.

To recover you could close down the aborted channel and create a new one.

Comment: There is no way to recover. At least I see no.

Comment: Shiraz, do you have any code samples for that particular case. I'm asking, because i do not open any connection explicitly, this happens in Discovery client internals.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this doesn't answer your question, but I feel a little wary about your code.  It seems fundamentally correct, but it feels like your discovery could be running very fast.  I would implement recurring discovery in a separate thread with some sleep time just to make the network happier. Just a thought to clean up the code. Sorry if this doesn't help.

```
  public void Start()
  {
    var bw = new System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker();
    bw.DoWork += new System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventHandler(DiscoveryThread);
    bw.RunWorkerAsync();
  }
  private void DiscoveryThread(object sender, System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs e)
  {
    var client = new DiscoveryClient(new UdpDiscoveryEndpoint());
    var findCriteria = new FindCriteria(typeof(ITestRunnerAgent))
                        {
                            Scopes = {new Uri(scope)},
                            Duration = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(DiscoveryIntervalInMiliseconds)
                        };
    while(true)
    {
      client.Find(findCriteria);
      // lock, clear, and add discovered endpoints to a global List of some sort
      System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
    }
  }
```

Comment: discovery works in a little bit another way, than you may think. When you call Find/FindAsync a broadcast message is sent across the network. After that the discovery module just waits for other computers to answer back. By default it waits for 20 seconds.

Comment: ah, so there is no way he is discovering faster than 20s. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As it is asynchronous operation the thread terminates after executing FindAsync(criteria) method. just wrote Console.Readline() after method call or use Autoreset event hold the thread.